# Sum all column value in a row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server that has 34 columns.

I need sum all column values in a row in SQL Server.

Table : `[CALEN]`

Columns:

```
YEAR_   | MONTH_  |D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5 .... | D31 | Days
------------------------------------------------------------
1392    | 12      | 1 | 1  | 2  | 1  |  4  ... | 0   | 29
```

I want calc count columns that have 1 value Calc this query:

```
select [All_column value is 1 and Start With D] 
FROM [CALEN]   
WHERE YEAR_ = 1392 and MONTH_ = 12
```

Comment: Assalamu 'Alaikum. By the term "sum all column value" did you mean the sum of values of ALL the columns, or only the D1, D2, D3 ... ... D31 columns?

Comment: Do you mean that you need a dynamic query which can work in each table or a query just for this table?

Comment: no. just for this table. I want calc count columns that have 1 value

Comment: @leylaazari, your question is a bit confusing. Add real data and your expected result to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unpivot your table:

```
SELECT  YEAR_, MONTH_, DAY_, COUNT_
FROM    (SELECT * FROM [CALEN] WHERE YEAR_ = 1392 and MONTH_ = 12) CALEN_FILTER
UNPIVOT (COUNT_ FOR DAY_ IN (D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10,
  D11, D12, D13, D14, D15, D16, D17, D18, D19,
  D20, D21, D22, D23, D24, D25, D26, D27, D28, D29,
  D30, D31)) AS CALEN_UNPIVOTED
```

Then you can easily make a common aggregate query, maybe easier puting the query above in a CTE, e.g,

```
WITH CALEN_U (YEAR_, MONTH_, DAY_, COUNT_) AS (
    SELECT  YEAR_, MONTH_, DAY_, COUNT_
    FROM    (SELECT * FROM [CALEN] WHERE YEAR_ = 1392 and MONTH_ = 12) CALEN_FILTER
    UNPIVOT (COUNT_ FOR DAY_ IN (D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10,
      D11, D12, D13, D14, D15, D16, D17, D18, D19,
      D20, D21, D22, D23, D24, D25, D26, D27, D28, D29,
      D30, D31)) AS CALEN_UNPIVOTED
)
SELECT YEAR_, MONTH_, COUNT(DAY_)
FROM CALEN_U 
WHERE COUNT_ = 1
GROUP BY YEAR_, MONTH_
```

Edit: see [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea504/2), using 10 days.

Comment: I have this error when use your code:Incorrect syntax near 'UNPIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.

Comment: I use Sqlserver2008R2.

Comment: I've added an sqlfiddle, which works fine for 10 days. Can't see a reason for your error, please check if all is typed well.

Comment: I use this code for compatibility error:ALTER DATABASE databasename
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100

Comment: how can i put this count in a variable in sql?

Comment: which count you mean? the filter or the result?

Comment: I want Result. COUNT(DaY_)

Comment: SET @mycount = (the query goes here); and remove year_, month_ from the SELECT

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN D1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN D2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN D3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN D4 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
.
.
.
CASE WHEN D31 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TOTAL_D
FROM [CALEN]   
WHERE YEAR_ = 1392 AND MONTH_ = 12
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/579c6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT D1, D2, D3, ... ... ... D31, 
(D1 + D2 + ... ... ... D31) as 'Days'
FROM [CALEN]
WHERE YEAR_ = 1392 and MONTH_ = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select year,month,D1,D2,D3....D31,
((nullif(count(D1),''))+(nullif(count(D2),''))+.....
(nullif(count(D31),''))) as Total
group by year, month
```