# Counting the number of columns greater than 0 for each row in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, count, sql-server-2012, calculated-columns

I have a table with more than 150 columns. is there any way to dynamically count columns greater than 0 for each customer.

table view is like :

```
     CustomerID  (SomeColumns)    Column1       Column2 ------------------ Column150
         1           -----           0            12        0  33  0  18       97
         2           -----           1             0        54  0  72  0        0
         .
         .
         .
```

This table has 500K rows. values of column1 to column150 are either 0 or not. how can I count the number of columns greater than 0 ?

Query:

```
Update Table
set NumOfColumnsGreaterThanZero = (select Sum(case when Column1 to Column150 >0 then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum all column value in a row in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434651/sum-all-column-value-in-a-row-in-sql-server)

Comment: please don't make a major change to the request 45 minutes after you posted it

Comment: I just posted a sample query to show what i meant. by the way, thanks for the heads up. @t-clausen.dk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dynamic SQL based on sys.columns, something like:

```
declare @columns varchar(8000), @sql varchar(8000)

set @columns = ''

select @columns = @columns + 'case when [' + name + '] > 0 then 1 else 0 end+'
from sys.columns 
where 
    object_id = object_id('TABLENAME') and 
    name not in ('not','wanted','columns') and 
    user_type_id in (select user_type_id from sys.types where name = 'int')


set @sql = 'select CustomerId, ' + @columns + '0 as VALUE from TABLENAME'
exec (@sql)
```

There is of course a risk with this approach that adding new columns to the table might cause unwanted results.

Comment: would you please explain user_type_id part in (--) part? @JamesZ

Comment: That's limiting the SQL for only int -type columns so you don't accidentally calculate strings which would cause an error. Other numeric types are ok too, you can see them with select * from sys.types

Comment: 'select CustomerId, ' + //columns// + '0 as VALUE from myrealtable' is not a valid identifier. I get this error @JamesZ

Comment: i can use just one at-sign in comment. i used one for you, so i coudn't use at-sign before column @JamesZ

Comment: I know they need [], would you apply this correction in your answer? (edit) @JamesZ

Comment: Fixed that, and deleted some of my comments to make this shorter.

Comment: I replaced exec at-sign sql with exec (at-sign sql). error is gone. but all values are 0. but i know minimum value should be 1 at least. in some cases 20 or 30 columns have values greater than 0. @JamesZ

Comment: If you print out the sql, you can look at it yourself, and see what columns are there. Maybe the type limitation now ignores the columns you actually have.

Comment: No dear, though the columns i want to count are int, i even tested the query without that clause ( user_type_id). still are values are 0 @JamesZ

Comment: Just print out the SQL (print @sql) and see what columns are there / what kind of SQL it is. That should explain you how it works and what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic example using 3 columns on a temporary table. You could adapt that for your structure using Dynamic SQL.

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Customers
(
    CustomerID INT
    , SomeColumn VARCHAR(100)
    , Column1 INT
    , Column2 INT
    , Column3 INT
);


INSERT INTO #Customers
    (CustomerID, SomeColumn, Column1, Column2, Column3)
VALUES
    (1, 'aaa', 1, 0, 2)
    , (2, 'bbb', 0, 0, 3)
    , (3, 'ccc', 0, 0, 0)
```

**Actual query:**

```
SELECT CustomerID, SomeColumn, IIF(Column1 > 0, 1, 0) + IIF(Column2 > 0, 1, 0) + IIF(Column3 > 0, 1, 0) AS T
FROM #Customers
```

**Results look like this:**

```
CustomerID  SomeColumn  T
1           aaa         2
2           bbb         1
3           ccc         0
```

Comment: why are you using aggregate (MAX) ? Removing it and the group by  would not make any difference

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you have a valid reason for having 150 columns. However here is how you could count the values that are not 0 using Pivot:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(customer_id int, col1 int, col2 int, 
                     col3 int, col4 int, col5 int);  

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ,(2, 0, 2, 0, 4, 5) 

SELECT count(CASE WHEN columns <> 0 THEN 1 END), customer_id
FROM @table as p  
UNPIVOT      
(columns FOR Seq IN           
([col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5]) ) AS unpvt  
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Result:

```
5   1
3   2
```

If you want to select the columns dynamically:

```
CREATE TABLE 
  test_table(customer_id int, col1 int, col2 int,
             col3 int, col4 int, col5 int);  

INSERT INTO test_table
VALUES(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ,(2, 0, 2, 0, 4, 5) ;

DECLARE @columnnames varchar(max)
SELECT @columnnames = coalesce(@columnnames + ',['+ column_name + ']' , '['+ column_name + ']' )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns 
WHERE
  table_name = 'test_table' and 
  column_name like 'col[0-9]%' and
  table_schema = 'dbo'
ORDER BY column_name

DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 
'SELECT count(CASE WHEN columns <> 0 THEN 1 END), customer_id
FROM test_table as p  
UNPIVOT      
(columns FOR Seq IN           
('+@columnnames+') ) AS unpvt  
GROUP BY customer_id'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 2):

to avoid i misunderstand your question, i try to create sample table and data, basically what i understand from your questions is, each of the columns are integer type, whenever the record is more then 0 then set to 1, else 0; this is good if you able to provide sample data and expected output. :)

```
CREATE TABLE tblTEST
(
COLUMN1 INT,
COLUMN2 INT,
COLUMN3 INT,
COLUMN4 INT,
COLUMN5 INT
)

INSERT INTO tblTEST
SELECT 1,0,5,12,6
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,10,0,12,6
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,30,5,0,6

DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Table_Name NVARCHAR(1000) = 'TBLTEST'
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @nStart INT = 1
DECLARE @nLast INt = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @Table_Name )

WHILE @nStart <=@nLast
BEGIN

SET @ColumnName = @ColumnName + ' CASE WHEN '+  (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM(SELECT COLUMN_NAME,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) RN FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @Table_Name) T1 WHERE RN=@nStart) + ' >0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END '+ (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM(SELECT COLUMN_NAME,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) RN FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @Table_Name) T1 WHERE RN=@nStart) + ','

SET @nStart = @nStart + 1
END

SET @ColumnName = SUBSTRING(@ColumnName,1,LEN(@ColumnName)-1)

SET @Query = 'SELECT ' + @ColumnName + ' FROM ' + @Table_Name

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @Query
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use dynamic sql and while cycle

**Sample data**

```
 -- Populate some sample data

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T;

CREATE TABLE #T
 (Column1 INT, Column2 INT, Column3 INT, Column4 INT, Column5 INT);

INSERT INTO #T VALUES 
 (0,0,0,1,0), 
 (0,1,0,1,0), 
 (1,0,0,2,0), 
 (1,0,0,0,1);
```

**Dynamic SQL with while cycle**

```
DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE (HasZeroValue TINYINT);
-- Number of columns to search for zero values
DECLARE @ColumnsCount INT = 5;
-- Dynamic sql statement
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @i INT = 1;

WHILE @i <= @ColumnsCount
BEGIN

 SET @SQL = 'SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM #T WHERE Column' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR) + ' > 0;'; 

 INSERT @ResultTable
 EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

 SET @i = @i + 1;

END

SELECT SUM(HasZeroValue) FROM @ResultTable;
```